# How to download videos from youtube on java?

Tags: java, youtube

how to download videos from youtube on Java?
need class(or piece of code) which describes how to do that.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download Youtube video in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198185/how-to-download-youtube-video-in-java)

Answer (score 28):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIUtils;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class JavaYoutubeDownloader {

 public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
 private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JavaYoutubeDownloader.class.getCanonicalName());
 private static final Level defaultLogLevelSelf = Level.FINER;
 private static final Level defaultLogLevel = Level.WARNING;
 private static final Logger rootlog = Logger.getLogger("");
 private static final String scheme = "http";
 private static final String host = "www.youtube.com";
 private static final Pattern commaPattern = Pattern.compile(",");
 private static final Pattern pipePattern = Pattern.compile("\\|");
 private static final char[] ILLEGAL_FILENAME_CHARACTERS = { '/', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\0', '\f', '`', '?', '*', '\\', '<', '>', '|', '\"', ':' };

 private static void usage(String error) {
  if (error != null) {
   System.err.println("Error: " + error);
  }
  System.err.println("usage: JavaYoutubeDownload VIDEO_ID DESTINATION_DIRECTORY");
  System.exit(-1);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
   usage("Missing video id. Extract from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID");
  }
  try {
   setupLogging();

   log.fine("Starting");
   String videoId = null;
   String outdir = ".";
   // TODO Ghetto command line parsing
   if (args.length == 1) {
    videoId = args[0];
   } else if (args.length == 2) {
    videoId = args[0];
    outdir = args[1];
   }

   int format = 18; // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs
   String encoding = "UTF-8";
   String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
   File outputDir = new File(outdir);
   String extension = getExtension(format);

   play(videoId, format, encoding, userAgent, outputDir, extension);

  } catch (Throwable t) {
   t.printStackTrace();
  }
  log.fine("Finished");
 }

 private static String getExtension(int format) {
  // TODO
  return "mp4";
 }

 private static void play(String videoId, int format, String encoding, String userAgent, File outputdir, String extension) throws Throwable {
  log.fine("Retrieving " + videoId);
  List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("video_id", videoId));
  qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fmt", "" + format));
  URI uri = getUri("get_video_info", qparams);

  CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
  HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
  localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
  httpget.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);

  log.finer("Executing " + uri);
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  if (entity != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
   InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
   String videoInfo = getStringFromInputStream(encoding, instream);
   if (videoInfo != null && videoInfo.length() > 0) {
    List<NameValuePair> infoMap = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    URLEncodedUtils.parse(infoMap, new Scanner(videoInfo), encoding);
    String token = null;
    String downloadUrl = null;
    String filename = videoId;

    for (NameValuePair pair : infoMap) {
     String key = pair.getName();
     String val = pair.getValue();
     log.finest(key + "=" + val);
     if (key.equals("token")) {
      token = val;
     } else if (key.equals("title")) {
      filename = val;
     } else if (key.equals("fmt_url_map")) {
      String[] formats = commaPattern.split(val);
      for (String fmt : formats) {
       String[] fmtPieces = pipePattern.split(fmt);
       if (fmtPieces.length == 2) {
        // in the end, download somethin!
        downloadUrl = fmtPieces[1];
        int pieceFormat = Integer.parseInt(fmtPieces[0]);
        if (pieceFormat == format) {
         // found what we want
         downloadUrl = fmtPieces[1];
         break;
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }

    filename = cleanFilename(filename);
    if (filename.length() == 0) {
     filename = videoId;
    } else {
     filename += "_" + videoId;
    }
    filename += "." + extension;
    File outputfile = new File(outputdir, filename);

    if (downloadUrl != null) {
     downloadWithHttpClient(userAgent, downloadUrl, outputfile);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 private static void downloadWithHttpClient(String userAgent, String downloadUrl, File outputfile) throws Throwable {
  HttpGet httpget2 = new HttpGet(downloadUrl);
  httpget2.setHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);

  log.finer("Executing " + httpget2.getURI());
  HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpResponse response2 = httpclient2.execute(httpget2);
  HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
  if (entity2 != null && response2.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
   long length = entity2.getContentLength();
   InputStream instream2 = entity2.getContent();
   log.finer("Writing " + length + " bytes to " + outputfile);
   if (outputfile.exists()) {
    outputfile.delete();
   }
   FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
   try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int count = -1;
    while ((count = instream2.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     outstream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outstream.flush();
   } finally {
    outstream.close();
   }
  }
 }

 private static String cleanFilename(String filename) {
  for (char c : ILLEGAL_FILENAME_CHARACTERS) {
   filename = filename.replace(c, '_');
  }
  return filename;
 }

 private static URI getUri(String path, List<NameValuePair> qparams) throws URISyntaxException {
  URI uri = URIUtils.createURI(scheme, host, -1, "/" + path, URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, "UTF-8"), null);
  return uri;
 }

 private static void setupLogging() {
  changeFormatter(new Formatter() {
   @Override
   public String format(LogRecord arg0) {
    return arg0.getMessage() + newline;
   }
  });
  explicitlySetAllLogging(Level.FINER);
 }

 private static void changeFormatter(Formatter formatter) {
  Handler[] handlers = rootlog.getHandlers();
  for (Handler handler : handlers) {
   handler.setFormatter(formatter);
  }
 }

 private static void explicitlySetAllLogging(Level level) {
  rootlog.setLevel(Level.ALL);
  for (Handler handler : rootlog.getHandlers()) {
   handler.setLevel(defaultLogLevelSelf);
  }
  log.setLevel(level);
  rootlog.setLevel(defaultLogLevel);
 }

 private static String getStringFromInputStream(String encoding, InputStream instream) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
  Writer writer = new StringWriter();

  char[] buffer = new char[1024];
  try {
   Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, encoding));
   int n;
   while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
   }
  } finally {
   instream.close();
  }
  String result = writer.toString();
  return result;
 }
}

/**
 * <pre>
 * Exploded results from get_video_info:
 * 
 * fexp=90...
 * allow_embed=1
 * fmt_stream_map=35|http://v9.lscache8...
 * fmt_url_map=35|http://v9.lscache8...
 * allow_ratings=1
 * keywords=Stefan Molyneux,Luke Bessey,anarchy,stateless society,giant stone cow,the story of our unenslavement,market anarchy,voluntaryism,anarcho capitalism
 * track_embed=0
 * fmt_list=35/854x480/9/0/115,34/640x360/9/0/115,18/640x360/9/0/115,5/320x240/7/0/0
 * author=lukebessey
 * muted=0
 * length_seconds=390
 * plid=AA...
 * ftoken=null
 * status=ok
 * watermark=http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/logo-vfl_bP6ud.swf,http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/hdlogo-vfloR6wva.swf
 * timestamp=12...
 * has_cc=False
 * fmt_map=35/854x480/9/0/115,34/640x360/9/0/115,18/640x360/9/0/115,5/320x240/7/0/0
 * leanback_module=http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/leanback_module-vflJYyeZN.swf
 * hl=en_US
 * endscreen_module=http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/endscreen-vflk19iTq.swf
 * vq=auto
 * avg_rating=5.0
 * video_id=S6IZP3yRJ9I
 * token=vPpcFNh...
 * thumbnail_url=http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/S6IZP3yRJ9I/default.jpg
 * title=The Story of Our Unenslavement - Animated
 * </pre>
 */
```

Comment: Can you please tell that which jar files are you using

Comment: user1999257 - Google the "findjar" and "jarfinder" services

Comment: Stepphen can you write detailed links regarding the needed library?

Comment: It is download video but not full of video.For example video is 4 mb.This code downloads 140 kb.

Comment: Sorry to say but It might be old code, It is not working now.

Comment: @Sun posted answer which is working

Answer (score 15):

I know i am answering late. But this code may useful for some one. So i am attaching it here.

Use the following java code to download the videos from YouTube.

```java
package com.mycompany.ytd;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import com.github.axet.vget.VGet;

/**
 *
 * @author Manindar
 */
public class YTD {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s10ARdfQUOY";
            String path = "D:\\Manindar\\YTD\\";
            VGet v = new VGet(new URL(url), new File(path));
            v.download();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the below Dependency in your **POM.XML** file

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
    <artifactId>vget</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.33</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Sorry to say but It downloading vedio, audio seperately as two files.

Comment: @Ravi It worked fine for me(Downloaded single video file). Can you please check with another video link.

Comment: This worked up until about 10 days ago, now doesn't work using the latest version (1.2.6).

Comment: the problem might be with 480p videos. its should have any problem with 720p  videos.

Comment: does not work anymore. you just get the error "empty video download list"

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the format (mp4 or flv) decide which [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832306/playing-youtube-videos-in-a-windows-mobile-application/1007705#1007705) you want to use. Then use this [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/file-url-download.shtml) to download the video and save it into a local directory.

Comment: Hi i am able to generate youtube video downloadable links but how to know which format videos that url is going to provide

Answer (score 5):

Ref :[Youtube Video Download (Android/Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588551/youtube-video-download-android-java)

**Edit 3**

You can use the Lib : https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor

Ex :

```
String youtubeLink = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx";

new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
@Override
public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
    if (ytFiles != null) {
        int itag = 22;
    String downloadUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
    }
}
}.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
```

They decipherSignature using :

```
private boolean decipherSignature(final SparseArray<String> encSignatures) throws IOException {
    // Assume the functions don't change that much
    if (decipherFunctionName == null || decipherFunctions == null) {
        String decipherFunctUrl = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/" + decipherJsFileName;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String javascriptFile;
        URL url = new URL(decipherFunctUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            javascriptFile = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        if (LOGGING)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decipher FunctURL: " + decipherFunctUrl);
        Matcher mat = patSignatureDecFunction.matcher(javascriptFile);
        if (mat.find()) {
            decipherFunctionName = mat.group(1);
            if (LOGGING)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decipher Functname: " + decipherFunctionName);

            Pattern patMainVariable = Pattern.compile("(var |\\s|,|;)" + decipherFunctionName.replace("$", "\\$") +
                    "(=function\\((.{1,3})\\)\\{)");

            String mainDecipherFunct;

            mat = patMainVariable.matcher(javascriptFile);
            if (mat.find()) {
                mainDecipherFunct = "var " + decipherFunctionName + mat.group(2);
            } else {
                Pattern patMainFunction = Pattern.compile("function " + decipherFunctionName.replace("$", "\\$") +
                        "(\\((.{1,3})\\)\\{)");
                mat = patMainFunction.matcher(javascriptFile);
                if (!mat.find())
                    return false;
                mainDecipherFunct = "function " + decipherFunctionName + mat.group(2);
            }

            int startIndex = mat.end();

            for (int braces = 1, i = startIndex; i < javascriptFile.length(); i++) {
                if (braces == 0 && startIndex + 5 < i) {
                    mainDecipherFunct += javascriptFile.substring(startIndex, i) + ";";
                    break;
                }
                if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '{')
                    braces++;
                else if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '}')
                    braces--;
            }
            decipherFunctions = mainDecipherFunct;
            // Search the main function for extra functions and variables
            // needed for deciphering
            // Search for variables
            mat = patVariableFunction.matcher(mainDecipherFunct);
            while (mat.find()) {
                String variableDef = "var " + mat.group(2) + "={";
                if (decipherFunctions.contains(variableDef)) {
                    continue;
                }
                startIndex = javascriptFile.indexOf(variableDef) + variableDef.length();
                for (int braces = 1, i = startIndex; i < javascriptFile.length(); i++) {
                    if (braces == 0) {
                        decipherFunctions += variableDef + javascriptFile.substring(startIndex, i) + ";";
                        break;
                    }
                    if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '{')
                        braces++;
                    else if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '}')
                        braces--;
                }
            }
            // Search for functions
            mat = patFunction.matcher(mainDecipherFunct);
            while (mat.find()) {
                String functionDef = "function " + mat.group(2) + "(";
                if (decipherFunctions.contains(functionDef)) {
                    continue;
                }
                startIndex = javascriptFile.indexOf(functionDef) + functionDef.length();
                for (int braces = 0, i = startIndex; i < javascriptFile.length(); i++) {
                    if (braces == 0 && startIndex + 5 < i) {
                        decipherFunctions += functionDef + javascriptFile.substring(startIndex, i) + ";";
                        break;
                    }
                    if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '{')
                        braces++;
                    else if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '}')
                        braces--;
                }
            }

            if (LOGGING)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decipher Function: " + decipherFunctions);
            decipherViaWebView(encSignatures);
            if (CACHING) {
                writeDeciperFunctToChache();
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        decipherViaWebView(encSignatures);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now with use of this library **High Quality Videos** Lossing Audio so i use the [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) for `Murging Audio` and Video for Final Output

**Edit 1**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240012/9909365

**Why the previous answer not worked**

```
 Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("sig=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(url);
        String sig = null;
        if (m2.find()) {
            sig = m2.group(1);
        }
```

> As of November 2016, this is a little rough around the edges, but
>   displays the basic principle. The url_encoded_fmt_stream_map today
>   does not have a space after the colon (better make this optional) and
>   "`sig`" has been changed to "`signature`"
>
> and while i am debuging the code i found the new keyword its
>   `signature&s` in many video's URL

here edited answer

```
private static final HashMap<String, Meta> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Meta>();
```

**initTypeMap(); call first**

```
class Meta {
    public String num;
    public String type;
    public String ext;

    Meta(String num, String ext, String type) {
        this.num = num;
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Video {
    public String ext = "";
    public String type = "";
    public String url = "";

    Video(String ext, String type, String url) {
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Video> getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(String ytUrl)
        throws IOException {
    if (ytUrl == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove any query params in query string after the watch?v=<vid> in
    // e.g.
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RUPACpf8Vs&feature=youtube_gdata_player
    int andIdx = ytUrl.indexOf('&');
    if (andIdx >= 0) {
        ytUrl = ytUrl.substring(0, andIdx);
    }

    // Get the HTML response
    /* String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";*/
   /* HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
            userAgent);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ytUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);*/
    String html = "";
    HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(ytUrl).openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line.replace("\\u0026", "&"));
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();

    // Parse the HTML response and extract the streaming URIs
    if (html.contains("verify-age-thumb")) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "YouTube is asking for age verification. We can't handle that sorry.");
        return null;
    }

    if (html.contains("das_captcha")) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Captcha found, please try with different IP address.");
        return null;
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("stream_map\":\"(.*?)?\"");
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)\"/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }

    if (matches.size() != 1) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Found zero or too many stream maps.");
        return null;
    }

    String urls[] = matches.get(0).split(",");
    HashMap<String, String> foundArray = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String ppUrl : urls) {
        String url = URLDecoder.decode(ppUrl, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("URL","URL : "+url);

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("itag=([0-9]+?)[&]");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(url);
        String itag = null;
        if (m1.find()) {
            itag = m1.group(1);
        }

        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("signature=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(url);
        String sig = null;
        if (m2.find()) {
            sig = m2.group(1);
        } else {
            Pattern p23 = Pattern.compile("signature&s=(.*?)[&]");
            Matcher m23 = p23.matcher(url);
            if (m23.find()) {
                sig = m23.group(1);
            }
        }

        Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("url=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(ppUrl);
        String um = null;
        if (m3.find()) {
            um = m3.group(1);
        }

        if (itag != null && sig != null && um != null) {
            Log.e("foundArray","Adding Value");
            foundArray.put(itag, URLDecoder.decode(um, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + "signature=" + sig);
        }
    }
    Log.e("foundArray","Size : "+foundArray.size());
    if (foundArray.size() == 0) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't find any URLs and corresponding signatures");
        return null;
    }


    ArrayList<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

    for (String format : typeMap.keySet()) {
        Meta meta = typeMap.get(format);

        if (foundArray.containsKey(format)) {
            Video newVideo = new Video(meta.ext, meta.type,
                    foundArray.get(format));
            videos.add(newVideo);
            Log.d("Downloader", "YouTube Video streaming details: ext:" + newVideo.ext
                    + ", type:" + newVideo.type + ", url:" + newVideo.url);
        }
    }

    return videos;
}

private class YouTubePageStreamUriGetter extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Video>> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(webViewActivity.this, "",
                "Connecting to YouTube...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Video> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<Video> fVideos = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            ArrayList<Video> videos = getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(url);
            /*                Log.e("Downloader","Size of Video : "+videos.size());*/
            if (videos != null && !videos.isEmpty()) {
                for (Video video : videos)
                {
                    Log.e("Downloader", "ext : " + video.ext);
                    if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp4") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("3gp") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("flv") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("webm")) {
                        ext = video.ext.toLowerCase();
                        fVideos.add(new Video(video.ext,video.type,video.url));
                    }
                }


                return fVideos;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't get YouTube streaming URL", e);
        }
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't get stream URI for " + url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Video> streamingUrl) {
        super.onPostExecute(streamingUrl);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (streamingUrl != null) {
            if (!streamingUrl.isEmpty()) {
                //Log.e("Steaming Url", "Value : " + streamingUrl);

                for (int i = 0; i < streamingUrl.size(); i++) {
                    Video fX = streamingUrl.get(i);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "URL : " + fX.url);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "TYPE : " + fX.type);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "EXT : " + fX.ext);
                }
                //new ProgressBack().execute(new String[]{streamingUrl, filename + "." + ext});
            }
        }
    }
}
public void initTypeMap()
{
    typeMap.put("13", new Meta("13", "3GP", "Low Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("17", new Meta("17", "3GP", "Medium Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("36", new Meta("36", "3GP", "High Quality - 320x240"));
    typeMap.put("5", new Meta("5", "FLV", "Low Quality - 400x226"));
    typeMap.put("6", new Meta("6", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("34", new Meta("34", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("35", new Meta("35", "FLV", "High Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("43", new Meta("43", "WEBM", "Low Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("44", new Meta("44", "WEBM", "Medium Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("45", new Meta("45", "WEBM", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("18", new Meta("18", "MP4", "Medium Quality - 480x360"));
    typeMap.put("22", new Meta("22", "MP4", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("37", new Meta("37", "MP4", "High Quality - 1920x1080"));
    typeMap.put("33", new Meta("38", "MP4", "High Quality - 4096x230"));
}
```

**Edit 2:**

> Some time This Code Not worked proper

**Same-origin policy**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

```
problem of Same-origin policy. Essentially, you cannot download this file from www.youtube.com because they are different domains. A workaround of this problem is [CORS][1].
```

Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/773719/how-do-all-of-these-save-video-from-youtube-services-work/773998#773998

```
url_encoded_fmt_stream_map // traditional: contains video and audio stream
adaptive_fmts              // DASH: contains video or audio stream
```

Each of these is a comma separated array of what I would call "stream objects". Each "stream object" will contain values like this

```
url  // direct HTTP link to a video
itag // code specifying the quality
s    // signature, security measure to counter downloading
```

Each URL will be encoded so you will need to decode them. Now the tricky part.

YouTube has at least 3 security levels for their videos

```
unsecured // as expected, you can download these with just the unencoded URL
s         // see below
RTMPE     // uses "rtmpe://" protocol, no known method for these
```

The RTMPE videos are typically used on official full length movies, and are protected with SWF Verification Type 2. This has been around since 2011 and has yet to be reverse engineered.

The type "s" videos are the most difficult that can actually be downloaded. You will typcially see these on VEVO videos and the like. They start with a signature such as

AA5D05FA7771AD4868BA4C977C3DEAAC620DE020E.0F421820F42978A1F8EAFCDAC4EF507DB5
Then the signature is scrambled with a function like this

```
function mo(a) {
  a = a.split("");
  a = lo.rw(a, 1);
  a = lo.rw(a, 32);
  a = lo.IC(a, 1);
  a = lo.wS(a, 77);
  a = lo.IC(a, 3);
  a = lo.wS(a, 77);
  a = lo.IC(a, 3);
  a = lo.wS(a, 44);
  return a.join("")
}
```

This function is dynamic, it typically changes every day. To make it more difficult the function is hosted at a URL such as

http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-en_US-vflycBCEX.js

this introduces the problem of Same-origin policy. Essentially, you cannot download this file from www.youtube.com because they are different domains. A workaround of this problem is CORS. With CORS, s.ytimg.com could add this header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.youtube.com
```

and it would allow the JavaScript to download from www.youtube.com. Of course they do not do this. A workaround for this workaround is to use a CORS proxy. This is a proxy that responds with the following header to all requests

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So, now that you have proxied your JS file, and used the function to scramble the signature, you can use that in the querystring to download a video.

Answer (score 3):

[`ytd2`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ytd2/) is a fully functional YouTube video downloader. [Check out its source code](https://sourceforge.net/p/ytd2/code/HEAD/tree/branches/) if you want to see how it's done.

Alternatively, you can also call an external process like [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) to do the job. This is probably the easiest solution but it isn't in "pure" Java.