# How do I determine the video file size on youtube in Java?

Tags: java, video, youtube, download

I am using the [youtube-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java) to gather different information about videos. The only missing attribute until now is size. The API itself doesn't provide any functionality.
I googled, but didn't found any solution.

Indirect way
My next idea was to get the path to the video-file itself and make a get-request. In the response-headers I could check for the file size. So I searched for "video / download / youtube / java". Some time ago youtube used [get_video_info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881143/youtube-video-download-url) but this doesn't work today. I also found an application called [JavaYoutubeDownloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032766/how-to-download-videos-from-youtube-on-java) but it seems VERY complicated for just getting the file size and it doesn't work either (just prints finish, without downloading anything).

So is there a way to get the filesize of a video on youtube by using Java? If not, what would be a practical solution for this problem (a list of video_ids exists)?

**EDIT:**
I know how to get the size of a file, but I do not how to get the URL to the video file! So either I need a way to get the URL to the FLV of a youtube-Link or a way to determine the file size an other way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do a HEAD request to the .flv file with an URLConnection and get the content of the `Content-Length` header. Using setMethod("HEAD") will just return the headers without downloading the entire file.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post. I also need the link to the flv by using this solution.

Comment: From the ID, you can find the URL of the flv using: `http://www.youtube.com/get_video?fmt=5&video_id={ID}&t={SIGNATURE}`

Answer (score 3):

You could look for the Content-Length field on the HTTP header (According to the updated documentation, please check getContentLength() out).

Please refer to [Java URLConnection : how can I find out the size of a web file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263013/java-urlconnection-how-could-i-find-out-a-files-size)