# How to include the axet/vget library in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to use the [axet/vget](https://github.com/axet/vget) library that is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032766/how-to-download-videos-from-youtube-on-java) but I have no idea how to add it to netbeans. Normally, you right click on the project name, click library and "add jar/Folder". But here there are no `.jar` files, only `.java` files.

So I am asking how to include that specific library ([axet/vget](https://github.com/axet/vget)) to netbeans.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I'm seeing so far is via Maven. In Netbeans 7.3.1 New Project > Maven > Java/Web Application (choose the appropriate project type, name it and hit finish). Copy the `pom.xml` provided from the [website](https://github.com/axet/vget). Then in your maven project go to Project Files > pom.xml, paste it then hit clean and build. Maven will download all the JARs for your project. They'll also be stored somewhere on your machine so you'll have to find them yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot!Can I just carry on building my program because the jars are already there?

Comment: @DLJ You're welcome. Yes you may. As long as their pom was correct you should have all you need.

Comment: @DLJ Oh also, there are some pretty good tutorial on Netbeans' website. Consider going through the Maven one. I personally love Maven.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really understand Maven but I hear that it is a high level tool that build programs and I will definitely look at the tutorials

Comment: @DLJ "build programs" is a little too strong. It's a dependency manager. Think of it this way, instead of having to look for all the JARs yourself, it finds the jars for you (online or on our computer for example depending on the entries of the `pom.xml`). It really helps when you work on a big project with different people scattered over the world (or a building). What if you or one of your teammates forgot the save a JAR ? How would you know which one you need ? It relieves you of that task. All you do...

Comment: @DLJ is simply fill in the `pom.xml` and when another team member comes in, he pulls the project and lets Maven find all the necessary dependencies. That's how I use and view it anyway. I'm not that good at using it either. There might be more to it also, so Maven enthusiasts don't hate me.