# How can I use Youtube API to download my past Live Streaming event?

Tags: c#, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to find a way to use the YouTube API to download a Live Streaming event that I hosted. There is such a functionality on the UI:

[image]

But I can't find a YouTube API endpoint that would do that for me.

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: I think it's against the YouTube Terms of Service(https://www.youtube.com/t/terms), see part 5.B. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933132/download-youtube-videos-with-java-api) is also asking the same.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 AFAIK, it's not. It's a not a regular video, it's a video from my streaming event. From the same SO post: "You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content". There is such a link on the UI, I just can't find a way to use the API to do the same.