# Youtube Video Download (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, video, download, youtube

**Note:** Original Question Was Deleted

Original Question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240011/get-the-download-url-for-youtube-video-android-java/15240012#15240012

**here the answer is outdated, not working so i will post a new question and answering my self**

**OLDCODE**

```
new YouTubePageStreamUriGetter().execute("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GuqB1BQVr4");

class Meta {
    public String num;
    public String type;
    public String ext;

    Meta(String num, String ext, String type) {
        this.num = num;
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Video {
    public String ext = "";
    public String type = "";
    public String url = "";

    Video(String ext, String type, String url) {
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Video> getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(String ytUrl)
        throws IOException {
    if (ytUrl == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove any query params in query string after the watch?v=<vid> in
    // e.g.
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RUPACpf8Vs&feature=youtube_gdata_player
    int andIdx = ytUrl.indexOf('&');
    if (andIdx >= 0) {
        ytUrl = ytUrl.substring(0, andIdx);
    }

    // Get the HTML response
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
            userAgent);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ytUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    String html = "";
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line.replace("\\u0026", "&"));
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();

    // Parse the HTML response and extract the streaming URIs
    if (html.contains("verify-age-thumb")) {
        CLog.w("YouTube is asking for age verification. We can't handle that sorry.");
        return null;
    }

    if (html.contains("das_captcha")) {
        CLog.w("Captcha found, please try with different IP address.");
        return null;
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("stream_map\": \"(.*?)?\"");
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)\"/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }

    if (matches.size() != 1) {
        CLog.w("Found zero or too many stream maps.");
        return null;
    }

    String urls[] = matches.get(0).split(",");
    HashMap<String, String> foundArray = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String ppUrl : urls) {
        String url = URLDecoder.decode(ppUrl, "UTF-8");

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("itag=([0-9]+?)[&]");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(url);
        String itag = null;
        if (m1.find()) {
            itag = m1.group(1);
        }

        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("sig=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(url);
        String sig = null;
        if (m2.find()) {
            sig = m2.group(1);
        }

        Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("url=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(ppUrl);
        String um = null;
        if (m3.find()) {
            um = m3.group(1);
        }

        if (itag != null && sig != null && um != null) {
            foundArray.put(itag, URLDecoder.decode(um, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + "signature=" + sig);
        }
    }

    if (foundArray.size() == 0) {
        CLog.w("Couldn't find any URLs and corresponding signatures");
        return null;
    }

    HashMap<String, Meta> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Meta>();
    typeMap.put("13", new Meta("13", "3GP", "Low Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("17", new Meta("17", "3GP", "Medium Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("36", new Meta("36", "3GP", "High Quality - 320x240"));
    typeMap.put("5", new Meta("5", "FLV", "Low Quality - 400x226"));
    typeMap.put("6", new Meta("6", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("34", new Meta("34", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("35", new Meta("35", "FLV", "High Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("43", new Meta("43", "WEBM", "Low Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("44", new Meta("44", "WEBM", "Medium Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("45", new Meta("45", "WEBM", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("18", new Meta("18", "MP4", "Medium Quality - 480x360"));
    typeMap.put("22", new Meta("22", "MP4", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("37", new Meta("37", "MP4", "High Quality - 1920x1080"));
    typeMap.put("33", new Meta("38", "MP4", "High Quality - 4096x230"));

    ArrayList<Video> videos = new ArrayList<ARViewer.Video>();

    for (String format : typeMap.keySet()) {
        Meta meta = typeMap.get(format);

        if (foundArray.containsKey(format)) {
            Video newVideo = new Video(meta.ext, meta.type,
                    foundArray.get(format));
            videos.add(newVideo);
            CLog.d("YouTube Video streaming details: ext:" + newVideo.ext
                    + ", type:" + newVideo.type + ", url:" + newVideo.url);
        }
    }

    return videos;
}

private class YouTubePageStreamUriGetter extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ARViewer.this, "",
                "Connecting to YouTube...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            ArrayList<Video> videos = getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(url);
            if (videos != null && !videos.isEmpty()) {
                String retVidUrl = null;
                for (Video video : videos) {
                    if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp4")
                            && video.type.toLowerCase().contains("medium")) {
                        retVidUrl = video.url;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (retVidUrl == null) {
                    for (Video video : videos) {
                        if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("3gp")
                                && video.type.toLowerCase().contains(
                                        "medium")) {
                            retVidUrl = video.url;
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (retVidUrl == null) {

                    for (Video video : videos) {
                        if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp4")
                                && video.type.toLowerCase().contains("low")) {
                            retVidUrl = video.url;
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (retVidUrl == null) {
                    for (Video video : videos) {
                        if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("3gp")
                                && video.type.toLowerCase().contains("low")) {
                            retVidUrl = video.url;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return retVidUrl;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CLog.e("Couldn't get YouTube streaming URL", e);
        }
        CLog.w("Couldn't get stream URI for " + url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String streamingUrl) {
        super.onPostExecute(streamingUrl);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (streamingUrl != null) {
                         /* Do what ever you want with streamUrl */
        }
    }
}
```

**This Code is Not Working**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the download URL for YouTube video (Android/Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240011/get-the-download-url-for-youtube-video-android-java)

Comment: @TilmanB.akaNerdyyy u are right sir already mention that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 3**

You can use the Lib : https://github.com/HaarigerHarald/android-youtubeExtractor

Ex :

```
String youtubeLink = "http://youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx";

new YouTubeExtractor(this) {
@Override
public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
    if (ytFiles != null) {
        int itag = 22;
    String downloadUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
    }
}
}.extract(youtubeLink, true, true);
```

They decipherSignature using :

```
private boolean decipherSignature(final SparseArray<String> encSignatures) throws IOException {
    // Assume the functions don't change that much
    if (decipherFunctionName == null || decipherFunctions == null) {
        String decipherFunctUrl = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/" + decipherJsFileName;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String javascriptFile;
        URL url = new URL(decipherFunctUrl);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            javascriptFile = sb.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        if (LOGGING)
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decipher FunctURL: " + decipherFunctUrl);
        Matcher mat = patSignatureDecFunction.matcher(javascriptFile);
        if (mat.find()) {
            decipherFunctionName = mat.group(1);
            if (LOGGING)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decipher Functname: " + decipherFunctionName);

            Pattern patMainVariable = Pattern.compile("(var |\\s|,|;)" + decipherFunctionName.replace("$", "\\$") +
                    "(=function\\((.{1,3})\\)\\{)");

            String mainDecipherFunct;

            mat = patMainVariable.matcher(javascriptFile);
            if (mat.find()) {
                mainDecipherFunct = "var " + decipherFunctionName + mat.group(2);
            } else {
                Pattern patMainFunction = Pattern.compile("function " + decipherFunctionName.replace("$", "\\$") +
                        "(\\((.{1,3})\\)\\{)");
                mat = patMainFunction.matcher(javascriptFile);
                if (!mat.find())
                    return false;
                mainDecipherFunct = "function " + decipherFunctionName + mat.group(2);
            }

            int startIndex = mat.end();

            for (int braces = 1, i = startIndex; i < javascriptFile.length(); i++) {
                if (braces == 0 && startIndex + 5 < i) {
                    mainDecipherFunct += javascriptFile.substring(startIndex, i) + ";";
                    break;
                }
                if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '{')
                    braces++;
                else if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '}')
                    braces--;
            }
            decipherFunctions = mainDecipherFunct;
            // Search the main function for extra functions and variables
            // needed for deciphering
            // Search for variables
            mat = patVariableFunction.matcher(mainDecipherFunct);
            while (mat.find()) {
                String variableDef = "var " + mat.group(2) + "={";
                if (decipherFunctions.contains(variableDef)) {
                    continue;
                }
                startIndex = javascriptFile.indexOf(variableDef) + variableDef.length();
                for (int braces = 1, i = startIndex; i < javascriptFile.length(); i++) {
                    if (braces == 0) {
                        decipherFunctions += variableDef + javascriptFile.substring(startIndex, i) + ";";
                        break;
                    }
                    if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '{')
                        braces++;
                    else if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '}')
                        braces--;
                }
            }
            // Search for functions
            mat = patFunction.matcher(mainDecipherFunct);
            while (mat.find()) {
                String functionDef = "function " + mat.group(2) + "(";
                if (decipherFunctions.contains(functionDef)) {
                    continue;
                }
                startIndex = javascriptFile.indexOf(functionDef) + functionDef.length();
                for (int braces = 0, i = startIndex; i < javascriptFile.length(); i++) {
                    if (braces == 0 && startIndex + 5 < i) {
                        decipherFunctions += functionDef + javascriptFile.substring(startIndex, i) + ";";
                        break;
                    }
                    if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '{')
                        braces++;
                    else if (javascriptFile.charAt(i) == '}')
                        braces--;
                }
            }

            if (LOGGING)
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Decipher Function: " + decipherFunctions);
            decipherViaWebView(encSignatures);
            if (CACHING) {
                writeDeciperFunctToChache();
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        decipherViaWebView(encSignatures);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now with use of this library **High Quality Videos** Lossing Audio so i use the [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) for `Murging Audio` and Video for Final Output

**Edit 1**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240012/9909365

**Why the previous answer not worked**

```
 Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("sig=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(url);
        String sig = null;
        if (m2.find()) {
            sig = m2.group(1);
        }
```

> As of November 2016, this is a little rough around the edges, but
>   displays the basic principle. The url_encoded_fmt_stream_map today
>   does not have a space after the colon (better make this optional) and
>   "`sig`" has been changed to "`signature`"
>
> and while i am debuging the code i found the new keyword its
>   `signature&s` in many video's URL

here edited answer

```
private static final HashMap<String, Meta> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Meta>();
```

**initTypeMap(); call first**

```
class Meta {
    public String num;
    public String type;
    public String ext;

    Meta(String num, String ext, String type) {
        this.num = num;
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Video {
    public String ext = "";
    public String type = "";
    public String url = "";

    Video(String ext, String type, String url) {
        this.ext = ext;
        this.type = type;
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Video> getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(String ytUrl)
        throws IOException {
    if (ytUrl == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove any query params in query string after the watch?v=<vid> in
    // e.g.
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RUPACpf8Vs&feature=youtube_gdata_player
    int andIdx = ytUrl.indexOf('&');
    if (andIdx >= 0) {
        ytUrl = ytUrl.substring(0, andIdx);
    }

    // Get the HTML response
    /* String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";*/
   /* HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
            userAgent);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(ytUrl);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);*/
    String html = "";
    HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(ytUrl).openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        str.append(line.replace("\\u0026", "&"));
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();

    // Parse the HTML response and extract the streaming URIs
    if (html.contains("verify-age-thumb")) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "YouTube is asking for age verification. We can't handle that sorry.");
        return null;
    }

    if (html.contains("das_captcha")) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Captcha found, please try with different IP address.");
        return null;
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("stream_map\":\"(.*?)?\"");
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)\"/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group());
    }

    if (matches.size() != 1) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Found zero or too many stream maps.");
        return null;
    }

    String urls[] = matches.get(0).split(",");
    HashMap<String, String> foundArray = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String ppUrl : urls) {
        String url = URLDecoder.decode(ppUrl, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("URL","URL : "+url);

        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("itag=([0-9]+?)[&]");
        Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(url);
        String itag = null;
        if (m1.find()) {
            itag = m1.group(1);
        }

        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("signature=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(url);
        String sig = null;
        if (m2.find()) {
            sig = m2.group(1);
        } else {
            Pattern p23 = Pattern.compile("signature&s=(.*?)[&]");
            Matcher m23 = p23.matcher(url);
            if (m23.find()) {
                sig = m23.group(1);
            }
        }

        Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("url=(.*?)[&]");
        Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(ppUrl);
        String um = null;
        if (m3.find()) {
            um = m3.group(1);
        }

        if (itag != null && sig != null && um != null) {
            Log.e("foundArray","Adding Value");
            foundArray.put(itag, URLDecoder.decode(um, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + "signature=" + sig);
        }
    }
    Log.e("foundArray","Size : "+foundArray.size());
    if (foundArray.size() == 0) {
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't find any URLs and corresponding signatures");
        return null;
    }


    ArrayList<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

    for (String format : typeMap.keySet()) {
        Meta meta = typeMap.get(format);

        if (foundArray.containsKey(format)) {
            Video newVideo = new Video(meta.ext, meta.type,
                    foundArray.get(format));
            videos.add(newVideo);
            Log.d("Downloader", "YouTube Video streaming details: ext:" + newVideo.ext
                    + ", type:" + newVideo.type + ", url:" + newVideo.url);
        }
    }

    return videos;
}

private class YouTubePageStreamUriGetter extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Video>> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(webViewActivity.this, "",
                "Connecting to YouTube...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Video> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ArrayList<Video> fVideos = new ArrayList<>();
        String url = params[0];
        try {
            ArrayList<Video> videos = getStreamingUrisFromYouTubePage(url);
            /*                Log.e("Downloader","Size of Video : "+videos.size());*/
            if (videos != null && !videos.isEmpty()) {
                for (Video video : videos)
                {
                    Log.e("Downloader", "ext : " + video.ext);
                    if (video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("mp4") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("3gp") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("flv") || video.ext.toLowerCase().contains("webm")) {
                        ext = video.ext.toLowerCase();
                        fVideos.add(new Video(video.ext,video.type,video.url));
                    }
                }


                return fVideos;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't get YouTube streaming URL", e);
        }
        Log.e("Downloader", "Couldn't get stream URI for " + url);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Video> streamingUrl) {
        super.onPostExecute(streamingUrl);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (streamingUrl != null) {
            if (!streamingUrl.isEmpty()) {
                //Log.e("Steaming Url", "Value : " + streamingUrl);

                for (int i = 0; i < streamingUrl.size(); i++) {
                    Video fX = streamingUrl.get(i);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "URL : " + fX.url);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "TYPE : " + fX.type);
                    Log.e("Founded Video", "EXT : " + fX.ext);
                }
                //new ProgressBack().execute(new String[]{streamingUrl, filename + "." + ext});
            }
        }
    }
}
public void initTypeMap()
{
    typeMap.put("13", new Meta("13", "3GP", "Low Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("17", new Meta("17", "3GP", "Medium Quality - 176x144"));
    typeMap.put("36", new Meta("36", "3GP", "High Quality - 320x240"));
    typeMap.put("5", new Meta("5", "FLV", "Low Quality - 400x226"));
    typeMap.put("6", new Meta("6", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("34", new Meta("34", "FLV", "Medium Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("35", new Meta("35", "FLV", "High Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("43", new Meta("43", "WEBM", "Low Quality - 640x360"));
    typeMap.put("44", new Meta("44", "WEBM", "Medium Quality - 854x480"));
    typeMap.put("45", new Meta("45", "WEBM", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("18", new Meta("18", "MP4", "Medium Quality - 480x360"));
    typeMap.put("22", new Meta("22", "MP4", "High Quality - 1280x720"));
    typeMap.put("37", new Meta("37", "MP4", "High Quality - 1920x1080"));
    typeMap.put("33", new Meta("38", "MP4", "High Quality - 4096x230"));
}
```

**Edit 2:**

> Some time This Code Not worked proper

**Same-origin policy**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

```
problem of Same-origin policy. Essentially, you cannot download this file from www.youtube.com because they are different domains. A workaround of this problem is [CORS][1].
```

Ref : https://superuser.com/questions/773719/how-do-all-of-these-save-video-from-youtube-services-work/773998#773998

```
url_encoded_fmt_stream_map // traditional: contains video and audio stream
adaptive_fmts              // DASH: contains video or audio stream
```

Each of these is a comma separated array of what I would call "stream objects". Each "stream object" will contain values like this

```
url  // direct HTTP link to a video
itag // code specifying the quality
s    // signature, security measure to counter downloading
```

Each URL will be encoded so you will need to decode them. Now the tricky part.

YouTube has at least 3 security levels for their videos

```
unsecured // as expected, you can download these with just the unencoded URL
s         // see below
RTMPE     // uses "rtmpe://" protocol, no known method for these
```

The RTMPE videos are typically used on official full length movies, and are protected with SWF Verification Type 2. This has been around since 2011 and has yet to be reverse engineered.

The type "s" videos are the most difficult that can actually be downloaded. You will typcially see these on VEVO videos and the like. They start with a signature such as

AA5D05FA7771AD4868BA4C977C3DEAAC620DE020E.0F421820F42978A1F8EAFCDAC4EF507DB5
Then the signature is scrambled with a function like this

```
function mo(a) {
  a = a.split("");
  a = lo.rw(a, 1);
  a = lo.rw(a, 32);
  a = lo.IC(a, 1);
  a = lo.wS(a, 77);
  a = lo.IC(a, 3);
  a = lo.wS(a, 77);
  a = lo.IC(a, 3);
  a = lo.wS(a, 44);
  return a.join("")
}
```

This function is dynamic, it typically changes every day. To make it more difficult the function is hosted at a URL such as

http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/html5player-en_US-vflycBCEX.js

this introduces the problem of Same-origin policy. Essentially, you cannot download this file from www.youtube.com because they are different domains. A workaround of this problem is CORS. With CORS, s.ytimg.com could add this header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.youtube.com
```

and it would allow the JavaScript to download from www.youtube.com. Of course they do not do this. A workaround for this workaround is to use a CORS proxy. This is a proxy that responds with the following header to all requests

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So, now that you have proxied your JS file, and used the function to scramble the signature, you can use that in the querystring to download a video.