# How to play youtube videos in a silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, youtube

Is there a way this can be accomplished?

I might have a solution from this answer:

> > You can also grab YouTube videos as MP4, hopefully that expands your
> >     player options. You can look into
> >     DirectShow CF for playback
> >     functionality, or host some other
> >     player in your app that supports MP4
> >     or FLV.
>
> Trying to play it back through IE
>   mobile won't work, as the version
>   necessary of the Flash plug-in with
>   video playback support isn't available
>   (last time I checked).
>
> To get the MP4 file make a request to
>   this URL:
>
> "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id="
>   + videoID + "&t=" + token + "&fmt=18"
>
> To get the FLV use this:
>
> "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id="
>   + videoID + "&t=" + token
>
> To get the Token call this:
>
> "http://www.youtube.com/api2_rest?method=youtube.videos.get_video_token&video_id="
>   + videoID
>
> I wrote an app that would grab a
>   playlist of YouTube videos and sync
>   them up with my PocketPC, I used TCPMP
>   with the Flash add-on to playback the
>   video (externally from my app).
>   Although MP4 also worked on the PPC, I
>   stuck to FLVs because at the time some
>   videos on YouTube were not available
>   as MP4. I wouldn't be concerned about
>   this now.
>
> Sadly my PPC broke, now I'm doing
>   something similar on my iPhone but I
>   had to switch completely to the MP4
>   format. VLC's FLV playback on the
>   iPhone was too jerky for me.

[Playing YouTube videos in a Windows Mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832306/playing-youtube-videos-in-a-windows-mobile-application)

Comment: I saw some examples online that play youtube videos in Silverlight, but all of them are OOB applications. I need a solution for in browser application.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to play a YouTube video natively in Silverlight (and I don't think it will ever be). The closest thing you can do is use the JS interface and this'll fire up the devices native video player (if it's a mobile device) or play using Flash.

You can steal the FLV feeds, but that's very bad and you shouldn't do that!

Answer (score -1):

You can solve the issue by using a media element. A media element can play a audio or video or both. See here for more details. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980132%28v=vs.95%29.aspx